# If I am Lost in Time and Space during a reckoning effect resolution, do I continue to resolve remaining reckoning effects?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-forsaken-lore

Being lost in time and space leaves you immune to reckoning effects, but what if the reckoning effect of a mythos card is what causes you to become lost in time and space, and you still have a few other conditions to resolve (for the reckoning effect)? Can you stop as soon as you become lost in time and space?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my mind but I have no official ruling on this.

In general, you have to resolve *all* the reckoning effects and order should not matter.

However, during a reckoning: If you are devoured, that would end your turn right there. If you are either killed or driven insane, that does end your turn. Thus, it would seem logical that Lost In Time and Space would end your turn as well.

Thus you would not be doing *any* reckoning events after those ones.  You dodge those bullets for this turn.

Lost In Time And Space was added in an expansion, I am not sure if this is covered by the FAQ or not.

Even going by the golden rule of cooperative games: *If a rule can be interpreted in several ways, the right one is the least helpful to the players*, the reading would be that yes, you stop doing any reckoning events once you are Lost In Time And Space.

Comment: Do you have documentation to back this? I have found none, so my default conclusion is that because Lost in Time and Space is a feature added after the base game, that its qualifier that one with that condition cannot be affected by reckoning effects means all reckoning resolution is halted for that investigator the moment he gains that condition.

Comment: Then again, there is the general rule (I thought I read somewhere) where if there is ambiguity you are to use the ruling that makes the game harder for the investigators, so I'm really not certain which ruling to go with at this point without a reference.

Comment: @Joey: Answer edited.