# Should reckoning effects be executed as if done simultaneously?

Tags: eldritch-horror

Should reckoning effects on an investigator's conditions execute as if done simultaneously (starting with the lead investigator)?  Two situations come to mind here.

1) If a reckoning effect condition results in my investigator being blessed or cursed, should I wait until after resolving all other reckoning effects to put the new condition into play (i.e. not benefit from the blessed condition for the other reckoning effects)?  This would effectively be like executing the effects simultanously.

2) If a reckoning effect *kills* my investigator, should I resolve all other effects as well? The case I am thinking of is where the Dark Pact roll of 1 results in *another* investigator being devoured.  If my investigator dies from another effect, does he get to skip resolving this dark pact or should he have to resolve it as well, as if simultaneous?

Mostly, this question came to mind because of a recent answer on [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27400/if-i-am-lost-in-time-and-space-during-a-reckoning-effect-resolution-do-i-contin/27433#27433).

Answer (score 3):

You get to determine the order of the effects, but they do not happen simultaneously. Thus you should resolve curse effect first and blessings last.

Do note that if a reckoning effect causes you to gain a card (e.g. a condition) that has its own reckoning effect you do not have to resolve the reckoning effect on the new card until the next reckoning. Basically, once the reckoning phase begins, the list of things that need to be resolved is fixed for that round.

And, yes, if your investigator is defeated by a reckoning effect you do not continue to resolve reckoning effects on his/her remaining items. Defeats are immediate and you discard all conditions and tokens (except clues) and set the investigator aside along with his possessions. This can also cause you to loose beneficial effects that the investigator was providing to others on his/her space. So, again, the order you resolve the effects does matter, even between investigators where you are supposed to follow the usual turn order (lead first, then clockwise).

The case in the question you cite is a little less clear. Lost in time and space usually allows an investigator to skip resolving reckoning effects. But you could argue that all the items' reckoning effects are triggered already (just unresolved) and since you take the items with you you have to continue to resolve them all.

Comment: I could not find any definitive documentation that  implied how to treat that case where you are sent into Lost in Time and Space midway through the reckoning. I was tempted to say the condition and state of the player nullifies all further reckoning just by virtue of being in limbo, but can't really justify it fully because I don't really understand what it is that *causes* a reckoning. Is it the alignment of the stars over Earth? I feel I may have to default to simply picking the option that makes it harder for the investigators to win, something I read somewhere to do as a fallback.

Comment: Yes, that is a good, all purpose, fallback.